# phpmyadmin alerting "This operation could take a long time. Proceed anyway?"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using `phpmyadmin` to manage my database. In one of my tables, when I click to see the last page (30 records) of 60000 records, I get this alert:
"This operation could take a long time. Proceed anyway?" which in fact does not happen and it shows up records in a very short time.
By the way, my table structure is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE `documents` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

so why am I getting this alert?

Comment: You got the warning because PHPMyAdmin (correctly) concluded that there's a large offset involved. The way MySQL deals with such queries is this: it executes the query and obtains **all** the rows that satisfy the `WHERE` condition (if any). After that it moves to `$offset` and takes `$limit` amount of records. Basically, it will take 60k records and discard all but 30 records. If you conclude that MySQL is "stupid" for doing so, just ask yourself how you'd implement the desired behavior. There are methods to make this kind of offseting faster but it's not what the question is about.

Comment: Your answer seems to be wrong. Because I have another table in same database with 4 columns and over 4 million records and when I click on last page, the alert does not show up! The difference between two tables is their engine.The second one`s engine is MyIsam!

Comment: As much as I would love to debate and argue with you, sadly, my answer isn't wrong. You, of course, don't have to take my word for it and luckily - we're both dealing with IT, a branch where we can verify our statements with facts. For example, I verified mine by reading the source code of the engine. You simply tried to use a program (PHPMyAdmin) that you don't fully understand, working with a system that you don't fully understand (MySQL). Do you think it's wise to draw conclusions based on observation and not by reading the source and understanding the issue at hand?

Comment: So why does not it happen on the second table with 4 million records?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is an open source program, you can always search its code for mentioned message and see what kind of logic it implements to give you those warnings. My comment was related to **MySQL** and how MySQL works. You have sufficient information to find out the answer you're after, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

phpMyAdmin, as you know is a PHP based database management panel, it has to scan through the database to the last 30 rows, which means it is processing each record between 0 and 60000 to retrieve records 59970-60000.

Depending on how fast your web & sql server is, this can take a long time. The warning message is simply there to say that it could take a long time to get these records because of the size of your database.

Comment: Why would PHPMyAdmin have to scan anything? It just passes the query to MySQL which does the work, PHPMyAdmin simply sits there and waits for the response. Your answer is only half-correct, PHPMyAdmin only concluded (correctly) that there's a huge offset involved and that the operation might take a while. Second part of your answer is correct, first one isn't.

Comment: Your answer seems to be wrong. Because I have another table in same database with 4 columns and over 4 million records and when I click on last page, the alert does not show up! The difference between two tables is their engine.The second one`s engine is MyIsam!